# How to hide a Button base on value from Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I hide a `Button` based on a value from Firestore?
I know that I can do this in a way with the `Visibility` widget, and I have tried this with just a `Toggle` button and it works. But if I want to check if the user is admin, and then decide wether the `Button` should be visible or not.

I have this `loggedin` that I use to get the data from that specific user that is logged in.
And in my database I have a field Admin, with the value true or false.

Here is my code:

```
  class ClientHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = "client_home_page";
  const ClientHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ClientHomePage> createState() => _ClientHomePageState();
}

final scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();


class _ClientHomePageState extends State<ClientHomePage> {

  final _toolidController = TextEditingController();

  User? user =FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  UserModel loggedin = UserModel();



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {


      setState(() {
        loggedin = UserModel.fromMap(value.data());

      });
    });
    
  }
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldkey,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          'Client',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 22,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Admin web',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.admin_panel_settings,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 30,
            ),
            onPressed: (){
              if(loggedin.admin == 'true'){
                print('user admin');
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, WebHomePage.id);

              }else if (loggedin.admin == 'false'){
                print ('user not admin');
              }

              
              print('admin knapp trykket');
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Logg ut',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.logout,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 30,
            ),
            onPressed: (){
              FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, LoginUserPage.id);


              //logg ut funksjon
              print('logg ut knapp trykket');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(100, 20, 100, 0),
                child: Text(
                  'Du er innlogget som:',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                    color: Color(0xFF9E9E9E),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Center(child: Text('${loggedin.name}')),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 150, 0, 0),
                child: Text(
                  'Scan verktøy',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),

                ),
        
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Which widget you want to have that condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `loggedin.admin`, try this:

```
loggedin.admin == 'true' ? IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Admin web',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.admin_panel_settings,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 30,
            ),
            onPressed: (){},
          ): SizedBox()
```

In this case, `IconButton` only show when that condition was true.

Comment: using loggedin.admin is better than adding new variable and make your code complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a state bool like  `bool showButton = false;` and changed it after getting data.

```dart
  bool showButton = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      loggedin = UserModel.fromMap(value.data());
      if (loggedin.admin == 'true') {
        showButton = true;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

Now use

```dart
if(showButton) YourButton(),
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked aswell. But in this case I had to put it like this: `@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {


      setState(() {
        loggedin = UserModel.fromMap(value.data());
        if (loggedin.admin == 'true') {
          showButton = true;
        }

      });
    });

  }`